# Solution of SDE at finite time, continuity of pdf

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations, brownian-motion, continuity

I'm looking at the Langevin dynamics described by the following SDE

$$d X_t = - \nabla U(X_t) \, d t + \sqrt {2 \Sigma} \, d B_t,$$

where $X_t \in \mathbb R^d$, $\nabla U(\cdot)$ has some regularity conditions (let's say smooth and Lipschitz), and $B_t$ is a Brownian motion. $\Sigma$ can be thought to be identity.

I'm interested in the random variable $X(T)$, for a fixed $T.$ In particular, I would like to state that its probability density function is continuous. I believe I could prove such statement, given the regularity of my problem, but I cannot find proper reference for this.

Answer (score 4):

In Theorem 1.2 of the paper [Density and gradient estimates for non degenerate Brownian SDEs with unbounded measurable drift](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022039620304988), the authors prove that the transition density of the SDE
$$
\mathrm{d} X_t=b\left(t, X_t\right) \mathrm{d} t+\sigma\left(t, X_t\right) \mathrm{d} W_t, \quad t \geqslant 0, X_0=x
$$
is continuous under some mild conditions.

---

[image]
[image]

[image]